# Failed to build when run command "bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain"

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to build tensorflow on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with python 2.7, no GPU. when I run the following command on terminal followed from this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html#training-on-flowers):

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

it says failed to build with log:

```
ERROR: /home/yuan/tensorflow_source/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1826:1: Linking of rule '//tensorflow/python:_pywrap_tensorflow.so' failed: gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/yuan/.cache/bazel/_bazel_yuan/e5b8b6538ba16bbae5b1e0f5c26b7a12/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
  /usr/bin/gcc -shared -o bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so -Wl,--version-script tensorflow/tf_version_script.lds -pthread -Wl,-no-as-needed -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -pass-exit-codes '-Wl,--build-id=md5' '-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' -Wl,-S -Wl,@bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so-2.params): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/core/libversion_lib.a(version_info.pic.o): In function `tf_git_version()':
version_info.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `tf_git_version()'
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/core/libframework_internal.lo(version_info.pic.o):version_info.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/core/libversion_lib.a(version_info.pic.o): In function `tf_compiler_version()':
version_info.cc:(.text+0xd): multiple definition of `tf_compiler_version()'
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/tensorflow/core/libframework_internal.lo(version_info.pic.o):version_info.cc:(.text+0xd): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 52.885s, Critical Path: 34.63s
```

Here's my build environment:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit with RAM 12Gib
gcc version: 4.8.4
python version: 2.7.6
bazel version: 0.3.2
git version of tensorflow souce: v0.11.0rc0-1541-g3737ac3

Does anyone have idea to fix this error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David thanks for your help, it seems my ./configure result is not as expected.

I finally build successful by the following steps

1. sync tensorflow source to HEAD
2. run ./configure again, if have any error, refer to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5310).
3. run the build command again

   bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain

And my build result will have no error.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please click accept on my answer or any answers that resolved your problem.